# CSS tabs width auto-resize

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, html5-canvas

I am creating a new layout to learn about flex, some kind of holy grail but in flex. The problem I am facing is with the tabs nav, because I want the layout to work fine in PC and mobile I need the tabs to autoresize.

No scripts no plugins no complications, clean and simple CSS only.

I want the layout to display the tabs nav with a maximun of 1281 px width on PC and if the screen is smaller like on mobiles or tablets it will use the full with of small devices.

I am doing it this way:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  flex: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenido {
  width: 1280px;
  background: #212121;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  background-color: #212121;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: #212121;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

footer {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <div class="contenido">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'welcome')" id="defaultOpen">Welcome</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'airdrop')">Airdrop</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'presale')">Presale</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'roadmap')">Roadmap</button>
    </div>
    <div id="welcome" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Welcome</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="airdrop" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Airdrop</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="presale" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Presale</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="roadmap" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Roadmap</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

The problem is that using the width 1281 in css it does not autoresize in small screens like mobile, if I set % width it display wrong on small devices too...

What I need is:

On pc max 1281 px width, on mobile 98% of the device width. The Tabs is the problem. I want the tabs to be a 25% of any screen resolution so they always display inline blocks like.

What is the problem ?

Link to Fiddle for real time demo
https://jsfiddle.net/vzd8re35/

Comment: Why not make `.tab` a flex container too ? And  `max-width: 1280px;` instead of `width: 1280px;` Also since you know your breakpoints use media query

Comment: can you show me how in fiddle ? I am a noob :)

Comment: No, The end result isn't clear, So i can't write code that i'm not sure of, I gave you suggestions to guide you since you're trying to learn a new concept, Id suggest you delete everything and start over, and try to keep code limited only to flexbox, with the occasional background/border to help you see where everything is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting max-width to 1280px, and then setting width to 100% on the same element like so:

```
.contenido {
    max-width: 1280px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This means that the wrapper has a maximum width of 1280px, and can only grow to 100% of this or smaller.

Comment: I did it and it does not work because the tabs shrinks to around 300 px width